# Creating a Wizard with Friendly URLs in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, wizard

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 app. This app requires a wizard within it. The wizard contains three screens. I need their URLs to map to:

```
/wizard/step-1
/wizard/step-2
/wizard/step-3
```

In my WizardController, I have the following actions:

```
public ActionResult Step1()
{
  var model = new Step1Model();
  return View("~/Views/Wizard/Step1.cshtml", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddStep1(Step1Model previousModel)
{
  var model = new Step2Model();
  model.SomeValue = previousModel.SomeValue;

  return View("~/Views/Wizard/Step2.cshtml", model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddStep2(Step2Model previousModel)
{
  var model = new Step3Model();
  return View("~/Views/Wizard/Step3.cshtml", model);
}
```

While this approach works, my problem is that the browser URL doesn't update. How do I post the values from a step and redirect the user to a new URL with a different data model?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of your wizard's views where you call `Html.BeginForm()`, make sure you call an overload of it that accepts either the desired route, or desired controller, action, and other routing parameters. For example, in Step1.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Step-2", "MyWizard")) {
    // put view stuff in here for step #1, which will post to step #2
}
```

That will make the target URL "pretty", but it won't fix the action names themselves being "ugly". To fix that, there's a feature in MVC that will "rename" an action method to almost anything you want:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("step-2")] // this will make the effective name of this action be "step-2" instead of "AddStep1"
public ActionResult AddStep1(Step1Model previousModel)
{
    // code here
}
```

Assuming the app is using the default MVC route (controller/action/id), each step will have its own URL.